# How to replace an HTML element with another one?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, how can I replace this code of page:

```
<div class="parent">
    <!-- possibly other elements -->
    <div class="toselect">hello people</div>
    <!-- possibly other elements -->
</div>
```

with this one:

```
<div class="parent">
    <!-- possibly other elements -->
    <span class="new" style="color:red">hi guys</span>
    <!-- possibly other elements -->
</div>
```

? Note that number of .parent's children, full code of any element are not known. The only things known are a selector necessary to select the element to be replaced ('.toselect'), and the code of the element to be added.

Comment: Will there only ever be one element with the `.toselect` class-name? If there are multiple elements should they all be replaced? Should they all be replaced with the same element? When you tried to solve this problem where did you get stuck? Can you share that attempted JavaScript with us, to show us what you did and to let us explain why it didn't work (assuming that it didn't work as intended)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below code.

```js
document.getElementById("change").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var oldEle = document.querySelector(".toselect");
  var newEle = document.createElement("span");
  newEle.innerHTML = "hi guys";
  newEle.classList.add("new");
  newEle.style.color = "red";
  oldEle.parentNode.replaceChild(newEle, oldEle);
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div>other element</div>
    <div class="toselect">hello people</div>
    <div>other element</div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="change">Change Element</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use "outerHTML" instead of "innerHTML" on the object.